# Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I was developing in Angular and I've found a weird issue:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: ([object
>   Object], ?, ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).

Worth to say that the dependencies which appear as "?" are only the services made by me, the others are Angular objects or third-parties, and it happens in my entire all project only happening in my own dependencies.

I've already read almost everything that I've found in google, I already reviewed the known issues about circular dependencies and barrel imports.

Other things you should know are:

- The dependencies which don't works are hosted in their own project and published in my local/own/private npm repository.
- I'd publish those dependencies through gulp using `npc.`
- I'm not using aot.
- `@angular/cli: "1.7.4"`
- `@angular: "^5.2.6"`

I really suspect about metadata, but I don't find anything inside node_modules/myDependency/ which gives me a clue about corrupted or missing metadata.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: If you downvote give a reason. I don't see what's negative about this question. He's clearly tried to fix it but can't.

Comment: Sorry, I really wanna show you the code but I can't because it's property of the company where I'm working

Comment: I just wanna know if someone else ever had the same issue. Should I use other compiler instead ngc? The fact about only my already published dependencies fail, make me suspect about metadata

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: ([object Object], ?, ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).

The services defined by the `?` must be added to the `providers` section of the `NgModule` that provide those services.

Comment: They are in providers, i promise. Another thing that could help you is: when I decorate my dependencies with @Inject(MyClass) myClass: MyClass, it works, but I wouldn't like to mark every place where I use MyClass with @Inject, it seems to me a dirty workaround, I'm pretty sure there is something else going bad, but I can't figure out what it is

Comment: @AbnerJuarez are you injecting a service from the same application, or is it from an external library (for example, like a module from Material Angular)?

Comment: Let me give you more context. I have many little repos managed with Lerna, for example, I have a repo called @byte/ng-security, there I have a service called SecurityService.

Then, I have other repo called @byte/ng-components, where I have another service called ClientSearchService, that service makes use of SecurityService from @byte/ng-security. In @byte/ng-components I have a module called ClientSearchModule, there I have SecurityService and ClientSearchService as providers in the decorator.

The error happes when I import ClientSearchModule in runnable projects.

Comment: You might need to have ClientSearchModule export any modules it's imported. So that those modules are forwarded to any modules that import it.

Comment: I'm gonna try it, but I have suspicions because, like the case of @Inject I'd mention to you, it just works for where I'm making the change and probably fail in another place